# Using jQuery to call functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a jQuery script, and I have problems understanding how everything works, so basically I'm going to create a function instead of rewriting a lot of code, so this is how I've done it:

```
$('.chkboxes').on("change", ":checkbox", function () {
   if (this.checked) {                
       var yolo = this.id;
       switch(yolo) {
       case "chkBox1":
       break;
       case "chkBox2":
       addfield("yolo" , "yolo", "text", "yolo");
       break;
    }
}
```

and then I have a function named "addfield":

```
function addfield(class, name, type, id) {
  var fieldstring = '<tr class=" ' + class + '"><td>' + name + '</td><td><input type="' + type + '" id="' + id + '" name ="' + name + '" /></td></tr>';
  alert(fieldstring);
  $(fieldstring).hide().appendTo(wrapper).fadeIn(999);
}
```

But I don't get it to work, how should I do this, I keep seeing functions as java methods but it doesn't work the way I want it to work! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What about making a demo?

Comment: You can't use `class` as an identifier in Javascript: it's a reserved word.

Comment: Also, looking at your code, you want to use $(this) (jquery 'this') instead of the generic javascript 'this'.

Comment: when you use "yolo" as test-word a developer, somewhere in the world, die.

Comment: Functions as java methods? Where do you keep seeing this? What does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not allowed to use keywords like `class`, `var`, `new`, etc. in variable names, so you should change your

```
function addfield(class, name, type, id) {
  var fieldstring = '<tr class=" ' + class + '"><td>' + name + '</td><td><input type="' + type + '"            id="' + id + '" name ="' + name + '" /></td></tr>';
   alert(fieldstring);
   $(fieldstring).hide().appendTo(wrapper).fadeIn(999);
}
```

to

```
 function addfield(someArgRepresentsClass, name, type, id) {
  var fieldstring = '<tr class=" ' + someArgRepresentsClass + '"><td>' + name + '</td><td><input type="' + type + '"            id="' + id + '" name ="' + name + '" /></td></tr>';
   alert(fieldstring);
   $(fieldstring).hide().appendTo(wrapper).fadeIn(999);
}
```

By "use in variable names" i mean make the keyword variable name. You can write smth like `newClass` etc.

```
$('.chkboxes').on("change", ":checkbox", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.is(':checked')) {

        var yolo = $this.attr('id');
        if (yolo == "chkBox1"){ 
           break;
        } else if (yolo == "chkBox2"){
          addfield("yolo" , "yolo", "text", "yolo");
          break;
        }
    }
}
```

The second one is `this.id`, change it to `$(this).attr('id')`
And btw, don't use switch, in such cases, `if().. else` would be muuuch better.